# How to read/parse soap header request in WCF service created in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core

I have created a poc WCF service and i am able to call that service using SOAP UI or Postman. But for some project work, i need to parse the below soap security header

SOAP Header

```
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5351BA8068B753C930158868612679914"><wsse:Username>test user</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">CS++k5OEqKsJByVPPmUqcBkAeoQ=</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">VK+Ilb/zy80lFbfHAAQupg==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2020-05-05T13:42:06.798Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
```

startup.cs file looks like below

```
public class Startup
    {
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
             {

             services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();          
             services.AddSoapServiceOperationTuner(new ServiceOperationTuner());
            }
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
            app.UseSoapEndpoint<ITestService>("/Service.svc", binding, SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer);
        }
}
```

ServiceOperationTuner.cs class has the code to get the HttpContext object as shown below. Here Tune menthod will be called for any request made to WCF service

```
public void Tune(HttpContext httpContext, object serviceInstance, OperationDescription operation)
        {
}
```

httpContext object hold all the header details but not the soapenv:Header.

Can anyone help me to parse this soapenv:Header request in .Net core ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find the solution?
I am looking for the same thing

Comment: @Rémy Did you figure the issue out?

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei unfortunately no