# How to read SOAP envelope header / body in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf

I need to read SOAP envelope header in ASP.NET WCF service using SoapCore.

This is the soap header example:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5351BA8068B753C930158868612679914">
            <wsse:Username>test user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">CS++k5OEqKsJByVPPmUqcBkAeoQ=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">VK+Ilb/zy80lFbfHAAQupg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2020-05-05T13:42:06.798Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Can anyone help me to parse this `soapenv:Header` request in .NET Core?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of  [How to read/parse soap header request in WCF service created in .Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618341/how-to-read-parse-soap-header-request-in-wcf-service-created-in-net-core-3-1) - down to the timestamp in the wsu:Created element

Answer (score 0):

There is IMessageinspector interface in SoapCore:

```
     using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
     namespace SoapCore.Extensibility
     {
             public interface IMessageInspector
               {
                   object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message message);
                   void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState);
               }
      }
```

You can implement IMessageinspector, and then get the header of the SOAP message in the implementation class.

```
        public class MessageLogger : IMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message message)
    {
        message.Headers.GetHeader<string>(0);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In my code,it gets the first header of the SOAP message and the header is of type string.

For more information about MessageHeaders,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheaders.getheader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.0